# how to perform a key field lookup in a file using bash or awk?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I'm bit of a newbie to shell scripting and awk.  Could anyone suggest a more efficient and elegant solution to what I'm doing below to perform a key lookup between two files ?

Two input files:

File 1 - Contains a single column key field (server-metricname-minute) :

```
key_column  
server026-AckDelayAverage-00:01:00  
server026-AckDelayMax-00:01:00  
server026-AckSent-00:01:00  
server026-DigEnvValidationLatestTime-00:01:00  
server026-DigEnvValidationTimeAverage-00:01:00
```

File 2 - Comma separated containing the key field and number of other fields

```
key_column,host,date,minute,metricname, metric value  
server026-AckDelayAverage-00:01:00,server026,May 24 2016,00:01:00,AckDelayAverage,942  
server026-AckDelayMax-00:01:00,server026,May 24 2016,00:01:00,AckDelayMax,5855  
server026-AckSent-00:01:00,server026,May 24 2016,00:01:00,AckSent,49038
```

My logic is :

```
Loop through file1  
If key found in File2  
    print file1.key , file2.field3 , file2.field6 to file3  
else  
    print file1.key + 'KEY_NOT_FOUND' text to file3  
fi
```

So the file3 output should have a row for every record in file1.

The code below seems to work , but could anyone suggest a more efficient and elegant method of achieving this ?

```
while read key ;  
do  
        metric_found=`grep $key file2`  
    if [[ ! -z $metric_found ]]  
    then  
            echo ${metric_found} | awk -F "," '{print $1",$3,"$6}'  
    else  
            echo ${key},KEY_NOT_FOUND  
    fi  
done < file1
```

Example output from existing script based on the sample data :

```
server026-AckDelayAverage-00:01:00,May 24 2016,942  
server026-AckDelayMax-00:01:00,May 24 2016,5855  
server026-AckSent-00:01:00,May 24 2016,49038  
server026-DigEnvValidationLatestTime-23:59:00,KEY_NOT_FOUND  
server026-DigEnvValidationTimeAverage-23:59:00,KEY_NOT_FOUND
```

thanks..

Comment: If you are just looking for general comments and improvements, your question might be better suited to the code review site

Comment: Please read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) to understand some of the reasons why you should be using awk for this, not a shell loop.

Comment: Thank-you for the article. Very informative. I'll be using awk for this type of processing from now on.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR==FNR{a[$1]=1;b[$1]=$3;c[$1]=$6;}NR>FNR{if (a[$1]) print $1,b[$1],c[$1]; else print $1,"KEY_NOT_FOUND";}' file2 file1 > file3
```

Comment: thank-you,  for my understanding could you give an explanation of how this is working ?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==FNR { file2[$1] = $3 OFS $6; next }
FNR>1 { print $1, ($1 in file2 ? file2[$1] : "KEY_NOT_FOUND") }

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
server026-AckDelayAverage-00:01:00,May 24 2016,942
server026-AckDelayMax-00:01:00,May 24 2016,5855
server026-AckSent-00:01:00,May 24 2016,49038
server026-DigEnvValidationLatestTime-00:01:00,KEY_NOT_FOUND
server026-DigEnvValidationTimeAverage-00:01:00,KEY_NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: thank-you. For my understanding could you give an explanation of lines 2 &3 ?

Comment: `NR==FNR` is only true for the first file so line 2 populates an associative array mapping each of the first field values from file1 to the 2nd and 3rd fields from the same line. Line 3 just prints the contents of the file1 array indexed by the first field in file2 when present, using a ternary expression. I highly recommend the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.